# How can I launch my Django application internally for my company?

Tags: django, web-applications, software-design, software-distribution

I am in the process of building a fairly large data analytics web app using Django - however I am more of a data scientist than a software developer so I am unsure of a few things here.

The key issue I have is that the data this application contains is highly sensitive and there is a company-wide ban on microsites on their servers. As a result I cannot simply host this application on any old server or Heroku etc., and I'm not sure even a secure user authentication would suffice in this case without my company's own security layers included - something i'd be unlikely to get sorted in time for the project deadline.

Is there an easy way I can package the app into a desktop application that only members of my organisation can install? If so how I do go about this and how can I enable specific colleagues to install it? Or am I missing a much more obvious method?

Thanks

Comment: 1. You can't install "django app" on desktop. 2. What about the DB? Can it be hosted in the cloud?

Comment: Hi Tom, I guess I can try and persuade them to push the data into the company-wide DB, however I was hoping for an alternative that I can update myself more easily.